# Specifying which column a button will be placed in

Tags: android-layout

I am using `TableLayout`, and when I am placing a button, I want to specify which column the button should be placed in. For example, column 4.  The dirty way to go around this is to place 3 empty views before I place the button.

But, is there a better way? I was told to use `android:layout_column="4"` in the code, but it made the application crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I found is by using the  view its basically an empty view  that just takes up space in the view its placed in. Alternatively a  can be used, will be able to do what I wanted to do before BUT unfortunately the columns and rows aren't distributed evenly or automatically which is a drawback.